# how to configure hornetQ in multiple standalone jboss-as-7.1.1.Final server

Tags: java, hornetq

can you please guide in how to configure hornetQ in multiple standalone jboss-as-7.1.1.Final server

like -- i have one application which connect through load balancing to 3 standalone jboss server
so 1 client connect 1 jboss server through application
2 client connect 2 jboss server through same application
and 3 client connect 3 jboss server through same application

if 1 client publish message how client 2 and 3 subscribe this message through application

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: i want to implement server side push in our application. but problem is we have individual 2 jboss server with different IP which are connect through load balancer, so i want to just implement one client publish the request and others clients subscribe the same request